# Auto layout put uiview in centre of two uiview's

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

is There any way in auto layout to put one uiview in centre of left and right view's using storyboard.

Leading Constraints Trailing Constraint

```
-----LeftView------CenterView-------RightView------
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help center]. You can also read about [ask] a good question.

Comment: can you share screenshot of your storyboard for this view controler ?

Comment: you can use UIStackView for that https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Answer (score 0):

Put a dummy view between LeftView and RightView and make the left edge of this dummy view align with the right edge of the LeftView and do the same with the RightView. Then make CenterView align with this dummy view's center.

```
-----LeftView|#####Dummy_View#####|RightView------
                       ||
                   CenterView
```

Answer (score 0):

plz follow these instruction:-

1.set horizontal spacing from centre view to left view and centre view to right view.

2.add centre vertically constraint in between centre view and both left and right view.